# Linux virtualbox not booting system

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm using Linux mint system and I wanted to run Sierra Mac OS. After configuration and click button "Run" I have only black screen and nothing happens.

Please check my log file and attached screens.
[image]
[image]

[LOG FILE](https://file.re/2022/01/04/vbox/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but running Mac OS X on Virtualbox in linux will be very hard and it would require some editing of configuration files of the VM image itself, along with additional software in the guest, and probably further modifications. The performance of the guest will be quite bad and not what you would expect. My experience with doing this multiple times shows, that it is not worth it. The better option would be to use VMWare, as they are supporting it.

> Mac OS X guests:
>
> Mac OS X guests can only run on a certain host hardware. For details about license and host hardware limitations. See Section
> 3.1.1, “Mac OS X Guests” and check the Apple software license conditions.
>
> Oracle VM VirtualBox does not provide Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time.
>
> The graphics resolution currently defaults to 1024x768 as Mac OS X falls back to the built-in EFI display support. See Section 3.14.1,
> “Video Modes in EFI” for more information on how to change EFI video
> modes.
>
> Mac OS X guests only work with one CPU assigned to the VM. Support for SMP will be provided in a future release.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html)

So in the end, it is possible (I've done it), but you will be disappointed with the performance. I hope I saved you some time and headaches.

Comment: Thank you. I will try with VMWare.